# ow do I move password securely between api and web?

Tags: authentication, hash, password-management, jwt, challenge-response

I would like to ask how I should go about securely transmitting the password between two applications. I have two projects that work with each other. The first one is a project called `AuthApi`, which **authenticates the user and creates tokens**. Here I get the **email** and **password** and if they are correct, I generate tokens. The other one is my project that I call `MainApp`. I send my **email and password** information to `AuthApi` from this project. I do not want to send the password explicitly to AuthApi from here. What security precautions should I take at this point? Do I need to temporarily encrypt the sent password and decrypt it in `AuthApi`? What are your suggestions?
As a result of my research, I found a method called **challenge-response mechanism**, but I don't know if I will get the result I want. The text I found as the explanation of the Challenge-Response mechanism: The server sends a special value (challenge) to the client. The client hashes this value by combining it with the password and sends this hashed value back to the server. This method ensures that the client does not send its actual password.

Comment: Why would the default oAuth 2 flow not be sufficient?  Why would you need a different flow?  

Also why is TLS not viable?

Comment: I will have more than one web project, but they will all be able to log in to the system from a single API. In other words, my training module project and my personnel management system module project will be separate. I don't know what you mean by tls, I'm still new to this. I've been doing my research because my manager told me to create a streaming solution like this. What path should I follow at this point? @LvB

Comment: Both of your service should communicate via secure connection which is what [TLS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/transport-layer-security-tls/) will give you and is enough in your usecase.

Comment: As @defalt linked. TLS is what is behind “HTTPS”, and you really shouldn’t be making any API with logon if you don’t know what TLS is, nikki. 

Secondly, as is almost always the case, DO NOT ROLL YOUR OWN! Use established standards, such as OIDC & oAuth 2 (OIDC, uses this by default). 

And I would suggest using an established solution for authentication, such as [KeyCloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) which could be used for the desired functionality. As a bonus you only need to implement half of the authentication, saving you work.

Comment: If both projects are html you can use a URL fragment (aka `location.hash` in JS) to transmit data between apps w/o going over any network. You would still use c/r so that the password isn't in the browser's history, but hash passing is simple, fast and secure.